# accessing the first elemnt in the associative array in php

Tags: php, mysql, associative-array

I have the following sql that returns a row that is stored as an associative array in php

```
select count(*) as a from "tablename" where columnname = "some";
```

I know that this sql is going to return only one row with one column, namely 'a', each time its run. Is there a way to access that value instead of having to do a foreach loop.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, access the first array in your 2D array and then access the element with the key 'a':

```
$my_array[0]['a']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [reset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php).

```
$value = reset($array);
```

Comment: Well, arrays and associative arrays don't really differ in PHP. An array in PHP is an ordered hash map - associative or numeric-keyed, just a map.